# Why those calls to base64 classes return different results?

Tags: java, base64

My code:

```
private static String convertToBase64(String string)
{
    final byte[] encodeBase64 =
            org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(string
                    .getBytes());
    System.out.println(Hex.encodeHexString(encodeBase64));

    final byte[] data = string.getBytes();
    final String encoded =
            javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data);
    System.out.println(encoded);

    return encoded;
}
```

Now I'm calling it: `convertToBase64("stackoverflow");` and get following result:

```
6333526859327476646d56795a6d787664773d3d
c3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdw==
```

Why I get different results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Hex.encodeHexString will encode your String to hexcode, and the second one is a normal String

Comment: What should I do to get proper value from apache implementations?

Comment: i don't know this libary but try to print only encodeBase64 (without Hex.encodeHexString) or try to use encodeBase64String

Answer (score 2):

From the API doc of `Base64.encodeBase64()`:

> byte[] containing Base64 characters in their UTF-8 representation.

So instead

```
System.out.println(Hex.encodeHexString(encodeBase64));
```

you should write

```
System.out.println(new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8"));
```

BTW: You should never use the `String.getBytes()` version without explicit encoding, because the result depends on the default platform encoding (for Windows this is usually "Cp1252" and Linux "UTF-8").